# Why does the output change in a recursive method?

Tags: java

I have created a simple recursive method like this:

```
public void rec(int a) {
    if(a > 0) {
        rec(a - 1); 
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

the output for this method is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

And that's just great but the question is why when I write the print command outside the if statement the output starts from 0 not 1?

```
public void rec(int a) {
    if(a > 0) {
        rec(a - 1);
    }
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Comment: How do you call the method?

Comment: The if statement wasn't executing the print statement for `0` because you have `if(a > 0`)!

Comment: if(a>0) which mean not true when it is zero ... when you placed System.out.println outside **if** condition it will printing irrespective of the if condition.

Comment: jimizv I call it by creating an object from the class because it's in another class

Comment: Oooh I think I got it now when I typed the print command before the if condition! Sorry it was a stupid question :(

Answer (score 1):

> why when I write the print command outside the if statement the output starts from 0 not 1?

Because, in the first version, the `if (a > 0)` prevents the function from printing `0`. How about we look at what is happening here by including both prints:

```
public void rec ( int a) {
        
    if(a>0) {
        rec(a-1);
        System.out.println("Inside if: " + a);
    }
    System.out.println("After if: " + a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code

```
    public void rec(int a) {
     if(a > 0) {
       rec(a - 1); 
       System.out.println(a);
     }
    }
```

you recursively invoke the method rec() with "a" as the parameter value for the first method invocation and then "a-1" for all the subsequent method invocations.
The rec() method has if clause which only executes if the value of parameter "a" received is greater than 0.

if the value of "a" is 0 then the method simply does nothing and returns back to invoking point and prints the value of variable a in that method scope.

An important point is that the value of "a" in a method scope is not being altered only the parameter to the next method call is being altered (i.e a-1)

Let' say the initial method call is something like

```
    rec(5) // <-- method invoked with a = 5

    //method definition
    public void rec(int a) { // <-- a = 5
      if(a > 0) { //  5 > 0 ? True
        rec(a - 1); // rec(5-1) ie rec(4) but a = 5 still
        System.out.println(a); // <-- a = 5 in this method scope
      }
    }
```

To have a better idea you can read on scopes,methods and call Stacks.
This will give a better grasp on recursion as well.